# How is it safe to set `from` address using Web3.js or like API?

Tags: solidity, web3js

If Web3.js allows you to specify who is calling a contract method (below), what is to stop an attacker from using the API to fake `msg.sender`? I am writing a contract that does some validation using `msg.sender`, but am not sure if it is safe given examples like below.

```
// using the callback
myContract.methods.myMethod(123).call({from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe'}, function(error, result){
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way nobody can fake the `msg.sender` that you get in your smart contract. Unless an attacker stole your private key, and in this case, the attacker would not fake it, but be the new owner of the account.

There's no way to fake it because you really have to sign the transaction to be able to send it to the smart contract, and you use your private key to sign it. The nodes that receive your transaction will check and make sure that is a valid transaction, signed by the owner of the private key that generated that `from` address. If not, they will reject it as invalid and it will not make it anywhere.

The smart contract is only executed by valid transactions signed by the rightful owner of the private key that generated the `msg.sender` address.

We can query the blockchain or the data of a smart contract without singing transactions, but we cannot modify the state of the smart contract without signing a transaction and paying gas:

If you want to play around with the following code, don't forget to update the infura id to your infura endpoint id for the Rinbeky test network, where I deployed the contract at address 0x7aAf8f3e3C4880fF4cD7afc619F9CC3F5a570f49.

Read the comments in the code.

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");

// Don't forget to add your own infura endpoint id
const web3 = new Web3(
  "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<your infura id>"
);

const abi = [
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "decrement",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "increment",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "counter",
    outputs: [
      {
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "",
        type: "uint256",
      },
    ],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "getCounter",
    outputs: [
      {
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "",
        type: "uint256",
      },
    ],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "getSender",
    outputs: [
      {
        internalType: "address",
        name: "",
        type: "address",
      },
    ],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
];

// For calls that don't require signing a transaction to query the blockchain, we can fake the `from`
// But for calls that modify the state of a smart contract or the blockchain, we cannot fake it.
// We need to sign our transaction with the private key that generated the `from` address.
const counter = new web3.eth.Contract(
  abi,
  "0x7aAf8f3e3C4880fF4cD7afc619F9CC3F5a570f49",
  {
    from: "0x6827b8f6cc60497d9bf5210d602C0EcaFDF7C405",
  }
);

// Cannot actually `send` the transaction since I did not set up my private key here to be able to sign transactions.
// If I try to call .send(), then it will not work.
// const responseWithSend = counter.methods.getCounter().send();

// We can call .call() here because we just need to query the blockchain and any node can provide us with that information
// without actually signing a transaction.
const getCounterResponse = counter.methods.getCounter().call();

// In fact, we can even query the blockchain or a smart contract directly using `getStorageAt`,
// where the first parameter is the contract address and the second is the index of the variable in storage we need,
// in this case, 0 is the index of the counter variable we need.
web3.eth
  .getStorageAt("0x7aAf8f3e3C4880fF4cD7afc619F9CC3F5a570f49", 0)
  .then((counter) => {
    console.log("counter: ", counter);
  });

getCounterResponse.then((response) => {
  console.log("counter: ", response); // Transaction receipt
});

// The sender here will be the same that we setup in `from` above.
const getSenderResponse = counter.methods.getSender().call();
getSenderResponse.then((response) => {
  console.log("sender: ", response); // Transaction receipt
});
```

This is because for requests that don't require signing, we call one node and it serves us the information we need. But for transactions that will modify the state of a smart contract or the blockchain, the transaction will be broadcasted through the network and all the nodes in the network will validate it, so to prevent DoS attacks on the network, you need to sign your transaction with your private key and pay gas for your transaction to be broadcasted through the network.

Comment: So the above code example will require the user to sign the transaction right? Is it possible to call a contract method without a signature such as a view-only function? I am working with the Chainsafe Gaming SDK right now which has a method that appears to do that.

Comment: I updated my answer. Take a look.